# Better keyboard input for XNA games

Tags: input, xna

Default XNA input doesn't provide an event handler that may call some method during frame processing (between update calls, immediately when a key is pressed).

I tried using Nuclex.Input, but it has some flaws — keys like F10, Alt and Pause do not fire up assigned events. Some of those keys appear in `GetKeyboard().GetState().GetPressedKeys()` list, but some of them don't, which is unacceptable for making shortcuts.

I would be happy if there was a way to make the XNA's default input manager to work with events, but I haven't seen anyone say it's possible. So I'm probably looking for some other input manager that can give me any key press there can be with press/release event handler.

Or maybe there is some way to avoid using third-party library by using windows hooks like firing up handler event for any key press/release?

Or this whole XNA input way is whacked up and higher class game engines use a totally different approach?

---

I see [everybody](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XInput_games)'s been using XInput for the last few years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have resorted to using Nuclex.Input for my XNA game, but I'm still looking for better alternatives.

Some problems with Nuclex.Input are that it doesn't differentiate between left and right Shift or Ctrl buttons and doesn't detect some keys (including F10, left Alt, PrintScreen and Pause).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code from an old project of mine. It finds the difference between two `KeyboardState` objects. Specifically, it returns a `KeyboardState` containing the keys that are down in the second one but not the first one.

```
KeyboardState GetKeysPressedBetween(KeyboardState first, KeyboardState second)
{
    KeyboardState pressed = new KeyboardState();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        FieldInfo currentStateI = typeof(KeyboardState).GetField("currentState" + i, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        uint firstCurrentStateI = (uint)currentStateI.GetValue(first);
        uint secondCurrentStateI = (uint)currentStateI.GetValue(second);
        currentStateI.SetValueDirect(__makeref(pressed), ~firstCurrentStateI & secondCurrentStateI);
    }
    return pressed;
}
```

This would normally be called once per frame, comparing the current state to the previous one.

The code could be modified to get the keys that were released, by replacing

```
~firstCurrentStateI & secondCurrentStateI
```

with

```
firstCurrentStateI & ~secondCurrentStateI
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my question mislead you into thinking I need a way to find difference between current and previous keyboard states. What I'm looking for is a way to react on each key press/release immediately, even between frames.

Comment: Do what? I need an event handler.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with processing your keys on the next Update?

Comment: Surely, you must have noticed that sometimes a key or a mouse button gets pressed and released too fast between two update calls for the game to detect it. It causes bad text input and missed clicks. It's not what I would call a satisfactory input management for a game.

Comment: Have you confirmed that this is a problem? I'd think it would be quite difficult to press and release a key in 1/60 second.

Comment: This is indeed a problem, because a frame is not always processed in 1/60 of a second. Games lag sometimes, not always because the frame takes too long to process, but because of other applications hogging resources. And while this is happening, it may be critical to press a button, or the game is lost :)

Comment: If you have tested this and found it to be an issue, you should make it clear in your question. If not, you should test it. As a side note, I believe XNA has a feature that allows it to skip rendering frames to maintain timely game processing, so sometimes lag will only be with rendering, not with actual updating.